# trying to setup a basic join :has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a basic Users / Memberships / Groups

I want a user to navigate to the Groups#show if the user is logged in they are shown a "Join" button, if the user is not logged they are offered a link to the login/registration.

I can handle the if logged in stuff using devise.  The piece I don't know how to do is the Join...   The real piece I am trying to figure out is the view code I think. I don't need anyone to write the code.   just point me in the right direction and I'll figure it out...

I have all the basic code for this setup.  The the tables are created, the models exist... the relationship is instantiated.

My current membership controller

```
def create
  @membership = current_user.memberships.build(:group_id => params[:group_id])
  if @membership.save
    flash[:notice] = "You have joined this group."
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to join."
    redirect_to :back
  end
end

def destroy
  @membership = current_user.memberships.find(params[:id])
  @membership.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Removed membership."
      redirect_to :back
end
```

end

any direction would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you don't want the actual code, so here are a few pointers:

- You need a form.
- This form needs to post to the `create` action you've shown in your question.
- You need to post the correct `group_id`.

Do you need any more pointers? Check out the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), they're pretty good!

Comment: rdvdijk, thanks for the tips. IT helps.  I am trying to learn without just getting the code to fix my problem...  so I created a form_tag, with a hidden tag with the group.id in it and put a button_tag to wrap it up.  but the create_memberships_path doesn't work.  Should I modify the normal resources :memberships and include a collection?  thanks

Comment: Take a close look at the form action. That should point to your `create` action. Compare the generated HTML to the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: I am trying the following in my Group#show view.  I want users to join groups... :
  <%= form_tag(create_membership_path, :method => 'post') do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag @group.id %>
    <%= button_tag "Join Group"%>
  <% end %>
any ideas?

Comment: That looks good to me. Doesn't it work? Two things, maybe the `:method => 'post'` isn't necessary, and maybe try `submit_tag` in stead of `button tag`? Also, this is turning into a forum-like question, in stead of a short question with a definite answer. (See [#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask))

Comment: I'll poke with it.  and thanks for the not on #dontask.  I want to be a good citizen... Thanks for the help.  It is very appreciated.